# Background image gets cut after zoom in/out

Tags: css

The background image gets cut after zoom out. I can't use the background size, because it's a logo which will change dynamically. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post any code? Link to the live code?

Comment: Copy edited. Jeopardy compliance. (its = possessive, it's = "it is" or "it has". See for example <http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Its-and-It%27s>.)

Comment: Actually it is an web application.. So not able to give link
This is the css code used for the logo..

.logo-white {
  background: url(../img/imgBrand/logo-white.png) no-repeat;
  top: 25px;
  left: 45px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 12%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}